# Is it possible to run the Cisco NX-OS 6.x copy command without the prompt to select a VRF?

Tags: cisco, copy, cisco-nexus

I am currently working with a network scanning tool that logs into Cisco routers and runs commands on those routers. The problem I'm encountering has to do with what the copy command expects. The copy command (documentation link below) prompts the user:

> Enter vrf (If no input, current vrf 'default' is considered):

Pressing enter here will allow the copy command to start with the default vrf, which is what I would like to happen. However, the network scanning tool cannot be programmed to add an enter input, so the tool simply gets stuck at this prompt, expecting the copy to complete.

So, is there any way to have the copy command run without this vrf prompt? Maybe some configuration setting or an argument that could be added to the copy command? I would like the default VRF to always be used.

[Command reference, copy command on page 46/220](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/nx-os/fundamentals/command/reference/fnd_cmd.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The vrf statement is optional at least in the 7.x code on 5500's and 9K's I have access to at the moment as well on 6.2 on 7K's I've used recently.  Indeed, the point of the default vrf is that it's taken as the vrf when something else isn't specified.

One thing you might consider trying is the command:

```
routing-context vrf <vrf-name>
```

which will change the execution context to the vrf of your choice for the purposes of ping, ssh, etc.  Entering the same command with *default* will switch back to normal.